# Why is a bitdepth of anything other than 8 for stencil buffers discouraged

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

From the [wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format):

> Image formats can store a stencil value. Stencil values are unsigned integer used by Stencil Tests for various effects. All of the stencil-only image formats take the enumerator form GL_STENCIL_INDEX#, where "#" is the number of bits for the stencil value. The available bitdepths for the stencil are 1, 4, 8, and 16.

> Note: You are strongly advised to avoid using any bitdepth other than 8. Also, see the note below about combining depth and stencil images in a Framebuffer Object.

Why is using a bitdepth other than 8 strongly advised against?

Comment: Probably compatibility.

Comment: You do not refer to the official specification, this is just a wiki page and the author's opinion.

Comment: @Rabbid76 is there any reason you can think of for this?

Comment: Read the section about [Required formats](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Required_formats)

Comment: because on most nowadays HW only 8bit stencil works and other bit depts are not supported